# Detect whether script is running in the context of Buildbot

Tags: gitlab-ci, buildbot

Can a script that may be run by [Buildbot](https://buildbot.net/)'s [`ShellCommand`](http://docs.buildbot.net/0.8.5/reference/buildbot.steps.shell.ShellCommand-class.html) detect whether it is indeed running inside the context of Buildbot (e.g. as opposed to having been started manually in a shell)?

For instance, does Buildbot set any environment variables (such as GitLab's [`CI_JOB_STAGE`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/) that the script could inspect?

I am looking for a well-portable solution, so setting a proprietary environment variable e.g. at the level of some Buildbot builders or inspecting the script's parent process is not quite what I am looking for.

Answer (score 2):

At least, it can detect if it is in an interactive session (when launched manually) vs. launched non-interactively (from a script or, in this instance, [buildbox builder](https://docs.buildbot.net/latest/tutorial/fiveminutes.html#builders-the-workhorses)).
In a bash session, `$-` would display the current options set for the shell.

Change you job to include a call to your script with:

```
scriptshell=$- ./myscript.sh
```

In your script:

```sh
if [[ ${scriptshell} != *i* ]]; then
    echo "non-interractive (script)"
else
    echo "interractive (manual launch)
fi
```

Comment: This looks promising, but is there a variant that leaves invocations from the shell unchanged (`./myscript.sh`)? Changing the call in Buildbot e.g. into `... ./myscript.sh` is fine.

Comment: @rookie099 I never managed to made it work without that `scriptshell` being set *before* calling the script. Hence my proposition.

Comment: Yes, I see. (It's also a bit like inspecting the parent process.)